# What is the origin of shadow on circle of light around the observed SMBH of galaxy M87?

Tags: black-holes

In pictures of observed SMBH of galaxy M87there is a dark part in circle of light around it ,why?
The Event Horizon Telescope image of the core of M87 using 1.3 mm microwaves. The central dark spot is the shadow of M87* and is larger than the black hole's event https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messier_87

Comment: I have in Wikipedia  Messier 87